# Xamarin Shell Flyout created from database data[xaml version]

Tags: android, shell, xamarin.forms, flyout

I'm trying also to generate from a database list the Shell Flyout elements. But I am not sure that implementing directly in `AppShell.xaml.cs` is a good idea. Is it possible to do the same thing but in
xaml?

I saw something similarly in [Define FlyoutItem appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance). But I still can't figure it out.
Also, is it a good idea to implement code directly into `AppShell.xaml.cs` or `App.xaml.cs`?

```
            LocationLevelViewModel diudu = new LocationLevelViewModel();
            var lists = diudu.Items;
            foreach (var list in lists)
            {
                ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection();

                shell_section.Title = list.LocationName;
                shell_section.Icon = "icon_feed.png";
                shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new LocationLevelPage() });
                this.Items.Add(shell_section);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided, you could create a new class named `AppShellCS` and use teh code in a new AppShellCS.cs file like below. It works well. I made a simple example to test instead of database.

```
public class AppShellCS : Shell
{
    public AppShellCS()
    {
        LocationLevelViewModel diudu = new LocationLevelViewModel();
        //var lists = diudu.Items;
        var lists = new List<LocationLevelViewModel>
        {
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="A"},
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="B"},
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="C"}
        };

        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection();

            shell_section.Title = list.LocationName;
            shell_section.Icon = "tab_feed.png";
            shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new LocationLevelPage() });
            this.Items.Add(shell_section);               
        }             


    }
}
public class LocationLevelViewModel
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new AppShellCS();
    }
```

OutPut:

[image]

**If you want to add this in a exist Shell project, you could try the code below.**

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Routing.RegisterRoute("step", typeof(Page2));

        LocationLevelViewModel diudu = new LocationLevelViewModel();
        //var lists = diudu.Items;
        var lists = new List<LocationLevelViewModel>
        {
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="A"},
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="B"},
            new LocationLevelViewModel() {  LocationName="C"}
        };

        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection();

            shell_section.Title = list.LocationName;
            shell_section.Icon = "tab_feed.png";
            shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new LocationLevelPage() });
            this.Items.Add(shell_section);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

[image]